# Compare 2 lists of colours (unsorted and different length)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scipy

I have a task that is really stumping me. I have produced an algorithm that sorts colours into bins/sub-groups. I want to assess how well it works compared to *human intuition*. So I've created some lists of colours (my data) and manually gone through and sorted them into bins/sub-groups of how I think the algorithm should sort the colours (my ground truths).  Then I feed those same lists of colours (my data) to the algorithm and compare its sorting to my ground truths.

Here lies my problem. I don't know how best to compare the ground-truths to the results in order to assess how well the algorithm is working. Can anyone provide advice on how to compare 2 lists of colours?

Below is an example of the ground truth and algorithm result. I need to compare these 2 different lists of colours to see how close the result is to the ground truth (the left one). *As you can see; the number of bins changes, the length of each bin is variable and the order of colours in each bin is variable. The only constant is both lists will always have the same number of colours (they will just be sorted differently).* So this is why it makes it so complex (for me atleast) to figure out how to compare them.

[image]

Example input data, ie a just list of colours that is fed to the colour sorter:

> [[69,99,121],[59,91,103],[71,107,140],[97,132,162],[85,117,141],[94,136,153],[86,131,144],[65,99,118],[211,214,201],[204,204,191],[203,207,188],[215,216,203],[194,199,180],[222,215,200],[219,213,195],[214,206,191],[197,188,172],[186,177,160],[206,197,181],[206,196,183],[38,35,31],[5,5,12],[31,34,41],[42,39,34],[30,32,27],[12,8,9]]

Example output from the colour sorter (the colours above have been sorted into 4 bins/sub-groups):

> [
>       [[69,99,121],[59,91,103],[71,107,140],[97,132,162],[85,117,141],[94,136,153],[86,131,144],[65,99,118]],
>       [[211,214,201],[204,204,191],[203,207,188],[215,216,203],[194,199,180]],
>       [[222,215,200],[219,213,195],[214,206,191],[197,188,172],[186,177,160],[206,197,181],[206,196,183]],
>       [[38,35,31],[5,5,12],[31,34,41],[42,39,34],[30,32,27],[12,8,9]]
>   ]

Note: I can easily change the format of the sorted colours to something else (like a numpy array or histogram) if you think that would make it easier to compare. Note with a histogram, the number of bins needs to be the same for each so I'd need to pad one of the lists presumably.

**How can I compare these 2 python lists when sub-list order doesn't matter much, and the sub-list length is so variable?**

**Edit** Clarification of the problem: I think I have bin comparison solved (see below code). The problem is how to know which bin from ground truth to compare to which bin from results. For example, in the above image I need to compare bin 2 from ground truth (left side) to bin 1 from results (right side), ie, compare the orange bins from each of them. Also the problem arises when there is no bin from results to compare to ground truth.

```
def validator(result_bin, ground_truth_bin):
    # todo: padd the shorter bin with black values so each is the same length
    dists = cdist(result_bin, ground_truth_bin, 'euclidean')
    correct_guesses = np.sum(dists<25, axis=1)
    score = float(len(correct_guesses)) / len(ground_truth_bin)
    return score
```

Answer (score 0):

RGB is a very unfitting representation of human color perception.

Convert to [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) or [Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space). Then you could use e.g. [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) for each color pair.

Since your lists are different length, finding pairs to compare can be done in many ways. I can suggest a few.

- For each color in the longer list, find the closest color in the shorter list; use Euclidean length of the vector of differences as the scalar measure.
- For each color in the shorter list, find the closest color in the longer list, measure difference as above, and remove them from the longer list. Now you have two lists again, repeat the process. Now you have a list of difference measures; average it by the number of runs (arithmetic or geometric mean).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But remember the bins are not in order. So in my example image, I would be comparing bin 1 from ground truth (left) to bin 1 from results (right). But I should be comparing bin 2 (left) to bin 1 (right), ie the orange group from left to the orange group from right.

Comment: My answer does not assume sorting in either case. It spends _O(len(list1) * len(list2))_ time, though, because it scans one list for each element of another list. With reasonably short lists, this may be acceptably fast.